# Setting up a virtual COM port

Tags: 12.04, serial-port

Finally my Dell xps 13 has arrived. I was aware of this shortcoming when I bought it, however, now I wish to resolve it.

My question. In ubuntu 12.04 can I establish a VCP so that I'm able to receive serial data from my current projects. (Ie PIC, RPi etc). As I only have two usb ports I would like to 've able to turn this facility on/off.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

To create a pair of ports you will need a utility called "socat".

```
sudo apt-get install socat
```

**Creating ports**

```
socat PTY: PTY:
```

That should create and link the virtual port pair for as long as socat is running.

check [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualSerialPort) for more details.

Also check [this](http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/howto-vsp-socat/) it may help.

But buddy I think it's easier to user USB to serial converter.